# Перемещение div по горизонтали - справа налево и наоборот, и по диагонали при вертикальной прокрутке

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть начало кода.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var s = $(this).scrollTop(),
    d = $(document).height(),
    c = $(this).height();
  // Формула - окна где 
  // s - это распознание скрола, 
  // d - высота всего дом дерева,
  // c высота этого объкта - точнее окна.
  // Получается Скрол делим на высоту дом структуры минус высоту этого окна

  // Выбор двух элементов по классу тела и классу дивника.
  var leftBoxElements = $('body.home .square'); // Объявление переменной по адресу body class="home"> div class="square"
  var rightBoxElements = $('body.home .circle'); // Объявление переменной по адресу body class="home"> div class="circle"

  window.onscroll = function() {
    // var scrolled = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop; // Объявление Переменной - воозращение координаты Y окна ИЛИ документа.html.Y
    // document.getElementById('showScroll').innerHTML = scrolled + 'px';
    position = $block.offset();
    scrollPercent = (s / (d - c));
    var position = (scrollPercent * ($(document).width() - leftBoxElements.width()));
    // Элемент Два слева направо
    var position = (scrollPercent * ($(document).width() - rightBoxElements.width()));
  };
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  height: 2000px;
}

*,
 ::after,
 ::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.circle,
.square {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

.circle {
  right: 100px;
  bottom: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.square {
  left: 100px;
  top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="square"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Покажите как это должно быть и дополните код, чтобы он воспроизводился.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Объявление переменных
    var decorationElementOne = $('#horizontal-item_one-left');
    var decorationElementTwo = $('#horizontal-item_two-left');
    var decorationElementThree = $('#horizontal-item_three-right');
    var decorationElementFour = $('#horizontal-item_four-right');

    var lastScrollYPos = 0;

    var decorationElementFive = $('#vertical-item_six-right');
    var decorationElementSix = $('#vertical-item_five-right');
        // Проверка элементов, нет ли их, на других страницах!
        if(decorationElementOne.length > 0){
            // Задаём объектам начальное положение!
            var horStartDecorationElementOne = parseInt($(decorationElementOne).css('left'));
            var horStartDecorationElementTwo = parseInt($(decorationElementTwo).css('left'));
            var horStartDecorationElementThree = parseInt($(decorationElementThree).css('right'));
            var horStartDecorationElementFour = parseInt($(decorationElementFour).css('right'));
            
            $(window).scroll(function () {
                var s = $(this).scrollTop();
                var d = $(document).height();
                var c = $(this).height();

                // Формула - окна где s - это распознание скрола , d - высота всего дом дерева , c высота этого объкта - точнее окна.
                // Получается Скрол делим на высоту дом структуры минус высоту этого окна
                var scrollPercent = (s / (d - c));

                // Вычесления позиции
                var position = (scrollPercent * ($(document).width()));

                // Задаём css стиль переменным
                decorationElementOne.css({
                    'left': position + horStartDecorationElementOne
                });
                decorationElementTwo.css({
                    'left': position + horStartDecorationElementTwo
                });
                decorationElementThree.css({
                    'right': position + horStartDecorationElementThree
                });
                decorationElementFour.css({
                    'right': position + horStartDecorationElementFour
                });

                // Возвращает верхнюю и левую координаты
                var position = decorationElementFive.offset(),
                    positionTwo = decorationElementSix.offset(),
                    // Коэффициенты X и Y позволяют изменить направление и степень диагонального движения.
                    // Отрицательные значения инвертируют направление.
                    factorX = -1,
                    factorY = 1,
                    factorTwoX = -1,
                    factorTwoY = 1,
                    // извлекает текущую вертикальную позицию прокрутки и вычисляет относительное смещение
                    scrollYPos = $(this).scrollTop(),
                    offset = Math.abs(scrollYPos - lastScrollYPos),
                    // дельта колеса мыши перевернута относительно направления,
                    // поэтому нам нужно нормализовать его относительно направления
                    direction = scrollYPos > lastScrollYPos ? -1 : 1,
                    // рассчитывает новую позицию.
                    // ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ: если для множителей используются только целые числа,
                    // то `Math.floor ()` не требуется.
                    newTop = position.top + Math.floor(direction * offset * factorY),
                    newLeft = position.left - Math.floor(direction * offset * factorX),

                    newTwoTop = positionTwo.top + Math.floor(direction * offset * factorTwoY),
                    newTwoLeft = positionTwo.left + Math.floor(direction * offset * factorTwoX);

                // Исполнения перемещения Дивников по Диагонально
                decorationElementFive.offset({ top: newTop, left: newLeft });
                decorationElementSix.offset({ top: newTwoTop, left: newTwoLeft });
                lastScrollYPos = scrollYPos;
            });
        }
});
```

```css
.decoration_element {
    height: 2000px;
    max-width: 1720px;
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
}
.decoration_element .decoration_element_one {
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    width: 130px;
    height: 120px;
    top: 240px;
    left: 230px;
}
.decoration_element .decoration_element_two {
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    width: 107px;
    height: 158px;
    top: 360px;
    left: 180px;
}
.decoration_element .decoration_element_three {
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    width: 123px;
    height: 120px;
    top: 180px;
    right: 180px;
    }
.decoration_element .decoration_element_four {
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    width: 61px;
    height: 61px;
    top: 400px;
    right: 180px;
}
.decoration_element .decoration_element_five {
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    width: 125px;
    height: 115px;
    top: 530px;
    left: 330px;
    }
.decoration_element .decoration_element_six {
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    width: 121px;
    height: 182px;
    top: 510px;
    right: 340px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="decoration_element">
    <div id="horizontal-item_one-left" class="decoration_element_one"></div>
    <div id="horizontal-item_two-left" class="decoration_element_two"></div>
    <div id="horizontal-item_three-right" class="decoration_element_three"></div>
    <div id="horizontal-item_four-right" class="decoration_element_four"></div>
    <div id="vertical-item_five-right" class="decoration_element_five"></div>
    <div id="vertical-item_six-right" class="decoration_element_six"></div>
</div>
```

Подключив jQuery Вы сможете испробовать у себя на локальной машине.